# Can't install to Cygwin's MinGW sysroot (it's protected)

Tags: compiling, directory-structure, cygwin, mingw

I have built a library with this command:

```
$ ../configure '--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32' --prefix=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw && make && make install
```

Installation fails because apparently there is no permission to create
files in mingw sysroot:

```
$ mkdir /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/share/whatever
mkdir: cannot create directory
‘/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/share/whatever’: Permission
denied
```

What's the problem and how can I solve it in most straightforward way?

Comment: I don't have access to my Cygwin or MinGW environment at the moment, so this is just a comment: To install something in a system path where no ordinary user has write permissions, you will have to be root.  If `sudo` is available, you may perform the installation step with `sudo make install`.

Comment: @Kusalananda there is no sudo in cygwin, every user is root I guess. This does not make it more clear I guess.

Comment: @Kusalananda trying priveleged cygwin run right now though, totally forgot about that.

Comment: Question related to `sudo` on Cygwin over at StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090301/root-user-sudo-equivalent-in-cygwin

Comment: @Kusalananda that was helpful but not in my case, `make install` was acting erratically plus it was running in separate window of CMD instead of mintty. The most universal solution is to start cygwin shell with escalated priveleges itself.

Comment: If that is an adequate solution for you and if you think that this could be useful for others to know, I'd recommend that you write it up as an answer. I would include a link to the StackOverflow question in that answer too.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `sudo` in Cygwin. Other sources sugest using

```
cygstart --action=runas command args
```

that was helpful but not in my case, `make install` was acting erratically because directory is not passed to the started process (it's a problem with `cygstart`) plus it was running in separate window of CMD instead of `mintty`. The most universal solution is to start Cygwin shell with escalated priveleges itself (you can redirect the output of the escalated command this way only):

```
cygstart --action=runas mintty -
```

but you stil need to navigate back to the directory where you wanted to execute command from.

I also found `-d` switch for `cygstart` which makes the command even worse:

```
#su analog
    cygstart --action=runas -d "$(pwd)" mintty -
#sudo analog
    cygstart --action=runas -d "$(pwd)" mintty command args
```

It could be the best solution but mintty does not pass directory EITHER without separate switch and it does not pass working directory to shell (`mintty -`).

So the final version of `sudo` is:

```
#new mintty window
    cygstart --action=runas mintty -dir "$(pwd)" command args
#new CMD window
    cygstart --action=runas -d "$(pwd)" command args
```

and I could not find a good way of starting shell in arbitrary working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just run as root: `su`, `sudo`, `runas`, it will work but leave problem for the future (there is a reason that these files/directories are protected).

There is a place set aside for you to install your own programs.

`/usr/local`

Putting it there makes it easier to upgrade your system, without loosing your program.

Even better, also use `stow`. It will keep your program separate form everything else, and use syslinks to patch it in. It will keep track of thinks so that it is easy to remove or upgrade.

Comment: This is not  completey related but informative. There is no `sudo` in Cygwin though.

Comment: There is also no `/usr` in Cygwin's MinGW sysroot as I learned now.